# Adding a bootstrap classpath when testing with Maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, bootstrapping

My library requires me to bootstrap the JVM in order to run it. In case you do not know, if you pass a jar to the JVM with the -bootstrap option, you can override (substitute) any Java library implementation like java.lang.String, etc.

So all I need to do is tell Maven that when it runs my tests it include the -bootclasspath option with my jar/classes.

Is that possible with Maven? Maybe maven will have to bootstrap itself, if the JVM is not able to add new bootstrap classes on-the-fly as it is able to add new classes/jar to the classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [argLine](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine) and the [forkMode](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkMode) parameters of the surefire plugin?

Comment: This will work, but not if it's a module from the current build that he needs to get into the boot class path.

Comment: @bmargulies. You can create a project dedicated specifically to running this special case test.  There you CAN pass the module as a dependency.  Maybe he would need to use maven-dependency-plugin for that

Comment: @Alex right. Build it first, then grab it for the tests. You just can't use it 'fresh from the reactor'.

Comment: I am building the classes the need to go into the bootclasspath. Then I do: <compilerArgument>-Xbootclasspath/p:${basedir}/target/classes/</compilerArgument>. But of course It does not work. :-( Maybe it is too late to change my bootclasspath? What do you suggest?

Comment: I was placing in the compiler plugin. Testing is done by the surefire plugin. argLine worked like a charm. THX!